# Can I create a Gutenberg component for use within InspectorControls, that accepts child components?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I've written a couple of custom WordPress blocks that both share some similar functionality: they both include a section in the `InspectorControls` that allows for iterating an array of data and displaying relevant input components. However, the input components used in each are different, depending on the data types.

For example, an array of objects containing two string properties could use two `TextControl` components:

```
// dataArray
[
    {
        a: 'Lorem ipsum',
        b: 'dolor sit amet'
    },
    {
        a: 'consectetur adipiscing',
        b: 'elit sed do'
    }
]

<InspectorControls>
    { dataArray.map( (data, index) => {
        return (
            <div className='multi-input__group' key={index}>
                <div className='multi-input__group-content'>
                    <TextControl value={ data.a } ... />
                    <TextControl value={ data.b } ... />
                </div>
                <div className='multi-input__group-actions'>
                    <Button icon='remove' ... />
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })}
</InspectorControls>
```

Or a number of different components could be used:

```
// dataArray
[
    {
        a: 'Lorem ipsum...',
        b: 'first select value'
    },
    {
        a: 'dolor sit amet...',
        b: 'second select value'
    }
]

<InspectorControls>
    { dataArray.map( (data, index) => {
        return (
            <div className='multi-input__group' key={index}>
                <div className='multi-input__group-content'>
                    <TextAreaControl value={ data.a } ... />
                    <SelectControl value={ data.b } ... />
                </div>
                <div className='multi-input__group-actions'>
                    <Button icon='remove'/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })}
</InspectorControls>
```

What I'm wondering now is: is it possible to abstract this pattern into a new component that accepts a data array, as well as the required child components, so that I don't have to repeat the various event handlers?

I've tried Slot/Fill without any success, as well as passing the component names as props. My instinct is that it would be best to pass the components within a props object that could also map them to the correct data and methods; but again, I haven't had any joy this way. Is it even possible to render a component with a dynamic name?